# C++11 static assertion fails noexcept check with Clang++?

Tags: c++11, clang, static-assert, noexcept

I'm trying to compile the following code with `clang++ -std=c++11 -c` and it fails:

```
void g() noexcept {}

template <typename Func>
void f(Func && func) noexcept(noexcept(func()))
{ static_assert(noexcept(func()), "func()"); } // No error!

void h() { f(&g); } // No error!

static_assert(noexcept(f(&g)), "Error!");
```

The error message Clang 3.4.2 gives me is:

```
test.h:9:1: error: static_assert failed "Error!"
static_assert(noexcept(f(&g)), "Error!");
^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Static assert needs to be evaluated at compile-time. How do you expected f(&g) to be evaluated at compile-time when it is not constexpr?

Comment: @michael-aaron-safyan `noexcept(something)` is always evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: nevermind. You're right. This is very curious.

Comment: GCC 4.7 and 4.9 compile this code without complaint, even with `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: In my mac, both static_assert will give me  error, Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0

Comment: @buzz The `noexcept` argument is not evaluated, hence it can't throw anything. It is even more puzzling that both `static_assert`s give an error on you Mac.

Comment: oh  gcc 4.9 acctually there aren't any problems in linux.

Comment: I don't understand why the `static_assert` would *not* fire. The instantiation of `f` that's called is `f<void(*)()>`, isn't it? So `noexcept(func())` should be `false`, since invoking a random statically-unknown function pointer may throw an exception. It seems like clang is obviously correct to me, and I don't understand the reasoning here for claiming otherwise. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @hvd `static_assert(noexcept(f(g)), "Error!");` fires as well.

Comment: @hvd Besides, isn't `func` is statically known?

Comment: @jotik Sure, and why wouldn't it? `f` is declared `noexcept(noexcept(func()))`, and `noexcept(func())` is `false`. (Yes, I see the same behaviour as buzz: both `static_assert`s fire.) As for whether `func` is statically known, no, and it cannot be. The `static_assert` is evaluated when `f<void(*)()>` is instantiated. It might be called with `&g`, but *that exact same function* might also be called with a pointer to a `noexcept(false)` function.

Comment: My cygwin clang++ 3.4.2 installaation and [this installation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8fa1d9bcf643bf5) both fire on either `static_assert`, as they should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`noexcept` is not a part of a function type.

Thus, `&g` is just your run of the mill expression of type `void(*)()`, with no special `noexcept` powers. So is `g`, as it decays to the function pointer. When such a function pointer is eventually called, it has no `noexcept` specification, and thus the entire expression is not `noexcept`.

Comment: So if GCC makes it possible to reliably check the `noexcept` status of a function call using a function pointer, should it be considered to be a bug?